# Storing large video files.

Tags: android, video

We are developing an video application, there are `100 video files around 15gb`. Is it possible to store videos in res folder? What is the best approach to store these videos in the application?

We are developing it for Tablet which contains 16gb memory card. How to store these videos in apk file and while installing the app we need to move videos to memory card.

`The main concern to store videos and while installing move to the memory card and later access videos from memory card.`

Please suggest the best approach. Thank you

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to store videos in res folder?

Not if you plan on distributing the app by any conventional means, like the Play Store. I'm skeptical that you can even create an APK that big.

> What is the best approach to store these videos in the application?

Not have them in the application, but rather somewhere else. Where that "somewhere else" is depends a bit on your planned app distribution channel. [Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), where you download the videos from within your app, are likely general-purpose candidates.

> while installing the app we need to move videos to memory card

On Android 4.3 and below, there is no official access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) ("memory card"). If you are limiting your app distribution to one specific model of tablet, you *may* be able to figure out some script-kiddie way of working with removable storage on that device.

On Android 4.4+, you can use `getExternalMediaDirs()` on `Context`; the second and subsequent entries in the list should be locations on removable storage.

Once you determine how and where you can gain access to removable storage, you can work on getting the videos there (e.g., download from a Web site on first run of the app).